# Getting a null promise when fetching with bearer auth

Tags: react-native, fetch

So, my fetch looks like this:

```
 fetch("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location='NYC'", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization:
        "Bearer MyApiKey",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.json());
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

And the result that I'm getting in the console is :

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

is my first time trying to fetch some data with Bearer in the Yelp API and I can't find a solution for this.

Thank you for reading this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
 fetch("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location='NYC'", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: new Headers({
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization:
        "Bearer "+YOUR_TOKEN,
    })
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.json());
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: I used axios and apparently it worked for me, but thank you !!

Comment: Great. Cheers !!